# Filezilla start after 25 seconds delay

Tags: filezilla, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10 fresh install.
command "strace filezilla" output stops on this lines:

poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
read(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000

And program starts only after 25 seconds.

When I updated version 19.04 to 19.10, there was no such problem. But after a clean install of 19.10, filezilla starts with a delay.

Comment: Please try with simple `sftp` and `scp`? Are they also slow? Maybe you can use the standard file browser 'Files` alias `nautilus` in standard Ubuntu for this purpose. If there is not a network problem, it might work where Filezilla is buggy.

Comment: sftp -oPort=2207 username@ip-address works fine.
I think the problem is starting the Filezilla client itself. I installed the snap version from the program manager and it starts quickly, without delay.

Comment: Good, you have solved the problem. Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: We can say that the problem is resolved. Perhaps this will help someone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bug/1848854/comments/10) : "sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module" and reboot.