# Ubuntu 19.10 gdb nearly unusable long delay

Tags: gdb

I am having a problem with the gnu debugger on Ubuntu 19.10. The problem presents itself as a long delay, somewhere between 20-30 seconds between running my program with gdb and my program actually appearing to run.

I typically use gdb with the integrated as a feature of the Larzarus development environment. Under normal circumstances when I run a program with the debugger the application I am testing appears nearly instant, but wuth Ubuntu 19.10 gdb takes a very long time in running my program. Again it takes between the time gdb starts my program and when my program appears to start between 20-30 seconds.

If I run my program manually from a terminal using gdb I get the same long delay. If I strip debugging symbols from my program and run with gdb again I experience a long delay.

I went back to a previous version of Ubuntu on this same machine and the problem does not present itself.

What might be be causing this problem? As it is right now the long delay makes development with the gnu debugger impractical on Ubuntu 19.10 and I'd like to see if there is a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

I also observed a delay in running some applications on Ubuntu 19.10.
Related questions:
[Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start), [Filezilla start after 25 seconds delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182155/filezilla-start-after-25-seconds-delay)

Try to run your program from a console using dbus-launch --exit-with-session and see if the delay still exists. You can also check what stops the program from running with strace.